# Wordpress - Multiple classes with different images

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

So, I am working on this theme and when I was exploring it secrets I found a class (.separator) that has an image inside of it.

```
.separator {
    background: url('../images/new/vector_header2.png');
}
```

As its written in PHP like this:

```
<div class="separator">
 <?php $headline = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'slogan', true); if($headline != '') { ?>
 <p>“<?php echo $headline;?>”</p>
 <?php } else echo '<p>&nbsp;</p>';?>
</div>
```

**That means for every post there is separator (class) to separate each new post. I want it go like that, but that it uses different images.**

I made two new separator classes (.separator2 and 3). Both of the have different images, but I have no clue what code language should I use for this. Whether its PHP or jQuery for checking each div or just having some kind of array that every time post its make it goes down 1 row and selects that image.

Full Loop is [here](http://pastebin.com/3hxHnAFD)

Comment: Do you plan to have a different class per post, ie each post will have a separator class attached to it to show a specific image. ie post1, will have the class separator1, or do you just want a bit of difference ie a random image from a selection for each separator, so post1 may use separator5 class and post2 may have separator1 class?

Comment: There will be 3 post in total, each post has its own class, that are the separator, separator2 and separator3.

Comment: @RedFiction12 can you show us the full code where your `loop` actually being kicked off?

Comment: I edited post check that link.

Answer (score 0):

If you place your `if` statement above the seperator `div`, you can easily add a custom `class` in which you define the new background image.

Something like:

```
<?php
$headline = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'slogan', true);
if($headline != '') {
?> 
 <div class="separator post_<?php echo $post->ID;?>">
  <p>“<?php echo $headline;?>”</p>
 </div>
<?php } else { ?>
 <div class="separator">
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
 </div>
<?php } ?>
```

---

Sorry, I misread the question.

If you want `.seperator1` `.seperator2` `.seperator3` etc to work you can do the following:

```
<?php
$count = 1;
$headline = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'slogan', true);
if($headline != '') {
?> 
 <div class="separator<?php echo $count;?>">
  <p>“<?php echo $headline;?>”</p>
 </div>
<?php if($count >=3) { $count = 1; } else { $count++; } 
}
?>
```

Comment: How it will add different `classes` on each row?

Comment: .post-ID {background-image: url('../img/new_image.png')}

Comment: OP wants to add `.separator1,2,3` classes not the `.post_ID*`